# How to get the IP address of a server using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

GOAL: 
Pull the IP address from the server. However, the issue comes into play that dedicated and VPS are very different. What is the best or most ideal way to pull and do a check and print the IP Address?

I guess I could do a check with the following?

```
root@host]# /sbin/ifconfig venet0:0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
IP IS HERE
root@host]# /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
eth0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
```

Comment: What VPS software is being used? Xen, Virtuozzo or something else?

Comment: This one is OpenVZ. But it would be ideal to be able to check them all. Don't all VPSes follow the same venet:0:0 for ifconfig?

Comment: I believe so. You can check my answer, it answers your question and provides a script that returns the IP address as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the IP address of your server whether it be a VPS or not you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

a="`netstat -i | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep eth0`";
b="`netstat -i | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep venet0:0`";

if [ "$a" == "eth0" ]; then
  echo "eth0 found"
  ip="`/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk -F':| +' '/inet addr/{print $4}'`";
elif [ "$b" == "venet0:0" ]; then
  echo "venet found"
  ip="`/sbin/ifconfig venet0:0 | awk -F':| +' '/inet addr/{print $4}'`"; 
fi

echo $ip;
```

Hope this helps.

Hat tip to [jwpat7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837847/jwpat7) for providing the awk command that is more succinct than the grep, cut, awk.

Answer (score 1):

See previous answer regarding how to determine which interface to look at.  The following shows how to replace your 3-process sequence of grep/cut/awk with a single awk.  Use either of the following forms.  In the first line, awk matches any line containing `inet addr` and after splitting on the default FS field separator of whitespace, splits on colon.  In the second line, awk splits on the regex of ":" or a string of spaces.

```
ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet addr/{split($2,a,":"); print a[2]}'
ifconfig eth0 | awk -F':| +' '/inet addr/{print $4}'
```